# why mappls-react-native-sdk not working even i followed documentation steps?

Tags: mapmyindia-api

i used `"react-native": "0.72.5"` .i added config or modification which are mentioned in the documentation, but i didn't work.

after installing mappls-map-react-native i followed documentation modification such as [mentioned in the below image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6Hnx.png). it didn't work. when i running npm start or react-native run-android i got error-

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':mappls-map-react-native:compileDebugAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':mappls-map-react-native:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.mappls.sdk:mappls-android-sdk:8.0.7.
     Required by:
         project :mappls-map-react-native
   > Could not find com.mappls.sdk:markerview-plugin:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :mappls-map-react-native
   > Could not find com.mappls.sdk:annotation-plugin:1.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :mappls-map-react-native
   > Could not find com.mappls.sdk:geoanalytics-plugin:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :mappls-map-react-native
```

how to resolve that.

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that all dependencies are properly installed.

You can check the documentation page here: https://github.com/mappls-api/mappls-react-native-sdk/blob/main/docs/v1.0.1/Getting-Started.md#installation